# ZAP alert categorization in owasp top 10 vulnerabilities

Tags: security, owasp, zap, websecurity

Could someone suggest around how to determine from ZAP report alerts that which alert fall under which OWASP top 10 vulnerability. For example, i had seen one example ZAP report where `Reference` column had `OWASP top 10 URL` as a value.

There are following columns in my ZAP report:

- Title
- Description
- URL
- Instances
- Solution
- Reference
- CWE ID
- WASC ID
- Source ID

Following are OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities:

https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

1. Injection Broken
2. Authentication
3. Sensitive Data Exposure
4. XML External Entities (XXE)
5. Broken Access control
6. Security misconfigurations
7. Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
8. Insecure Deserialization
9. Using Components with known vulnerabilities
10. Insufficient logging and monitoring

Although, it is obvious to say that we need to go through each alert in detail and logically map it to OWASP top 10. But was wondering if any alert attribute can help to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a document which maps various ZAP functionality top the top 10, here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/guides/zapping-the-top-10/